# How to made SSL connection for MarkLogic 7?

Tags: java, marklogic

I want to make a SSL connection as given on this `http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/SSL`

But I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Unrecognized
>   SSL message, plaintext connection?  [Session: user=demo, cb=Arg
>   [ContentSource: user=demo, cb=Arg [provider: SSLconn
>   address=localhost/127.0.0.1:9470, pool=0/64]]]  [Client: XCC/7.0-2]
>     at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:124)
>     at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:371)
>     at com.demoe2.MarklogicDemo.main(MarklogicDemo.java:41) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection?   at
>   sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source

My source code is for Java

```
public class MarklogicDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("xcc://demo:password@localhost:9470/Arg");
    query = "for $x in cts:search(//PLAY,cts:element-word-query(xs:QName(\"LINE\"),\"King\")) return ($x//TITLE)";    
    ContentSource con = 
      ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(
        "localhost", 9470,
        "demo", "password",
        "Arg", newTrustOptions());
    Session see = con.newSession();
    Request req = see.newAdhocQuery(query);
    ResultSequence rs = see.submitRequest (req);
    System.out.println (rs.asString());
    see.close();
  }

  protected static SecurityOptions newTrustOptions() throws Exception {
    TrustManager[] trust = 
      new TrustManager[] { 
        new X509TrustManager() {
          public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, 
            String s) throws CertificateException {
          }

          public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, 
            String s) throws CertificateException {
          }   
          public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
          }
        }
    };
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
    sslContext.init(null, trust, null);
    return new SecurityOptions(sslContext);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct port number?

Answer (score 1):

In the connection URL, use `xccs` instead of `xcc`.

You can also look at https://github.com/marklogic/xqsync/blob/1cf82faa2fa2e7fb3fa06f41e0938bf5b002b7fa/src/java/com/marklogic/ps/Connection.java#L100 to see an example that handles both `xcc` and `xccs`.